# HTML Field Type Input Number Only or Letter Only Without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, types

I create a form, where one field should only be filled with numbers.

I want that field can be filled **only with numbers** since entering input.

Like this example :

[How Can I Use Javascript to Allow Only Numbers to Be Entered in a TextBox?](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox)

I've tried using *Regex*, but when I try to input is still able to enter letters.

```
<input type="number" min="2" pattern="^[0-9]" class="andi_input required-entry" name="amount" id="amount" required title='Only Number' />
```

I want it when input to field and not after click the Submit button and the message appear and inform that the field can only be filled with numbers.

I also try to add `validate-number`, but the result is the same.

How, without javascript, so that the field can only be filled with numbers or letters?

Whether for this kind of case **have to use JavaScript** or is there another way without JavaScript?

Comment: You either use HTML5 validation which occurs on submit. Or you use Javascript (or a library that uses Javascript)

Comment: So had to use javascript? There is no other way without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a OneLiner:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return /[0-9]/i.test(event.key)">
```

or

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 uses the type="number" so make sure that the browser that you are using is compatible. Check it out in action [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number).

Comment: Thank you @travis-m for the reply / suggestion, but I mean / want is like this example [How Can I Use Javascript to Allow Only Numbers to Be Entered in a TextBox?](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox), where since the beginning of the input can not enter letters (numbers only), not after click Submit button

Comment: Sorry @travis-m, I want to click 'This answer is useful' to your answer but my reputation score is still less.

Answer (score 1):

You should check browser compatibility.
You're right with `<input type="number" pattern="^[0-9]" />`.

Your regex rule is : 
^[0-9] :

- ^ assert position at start of the string
- [0-9] match a single character present in the list below
      (0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9)

You can check your regex [here](https://regex101.com/).

I use to use HTML5 Validation and jQuery one because IE is capricious most of the time.

**UPDATE :**

Without Javascript it's not possible to check pattern on real time. I suggest you to use a jQuery library like : http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Formatting-User-Input-with-Specified-Pattern-formatter-js.html.

Comment: Thank you @delphine for the reply / suggestion, but I mean / want is like this example [How Can I Use Javascript to Allow Only Numbers to Be Entered in a TextBox?](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox), where since the beginning of the input can not enter letters (numbers only), not after click Submit button

Comment: I understand but without Javascript it's not possible and it was mentionned in your post title.

I suggest you to use a jQuery library like : http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Formatting-User-Input-with-Specified-Pattern-formatter-js.html.

Script in the link is working for you ?

Comment: Thank you @delphine, so the answer is without Javascript it's not possible :) I want to click 'This answer is useful' but my reputation score is still less. I'll accept your answer as an answer to approach the question.

Comment: I updated my answer so everyone can see the good solution and maybe you can tick it !